# NPM install issues Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: ubuntu, node.js, tar, npm

installing a fresh node with the following commands

```
sudo apt-get install git-core curl build-essential openssl libssl-dev
git clone https://github.com/joyent/node.git && cd node
./configure 
make
make install
node -v
v0.5.0-pre
```

works without a glitch. When I try to install NPM i get:

```
>/tmp/node$ curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  3874  100  3874    0     0   3033      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 22923
fetching: 

gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
It failed
>
```

I am using a VirtualBox NAT networking with no special proxy / firewall in the way.

trying `curl -s -L http://registry.npmjs.org/npm/latest` i get `{"error":"ucs","reason":"{bad_utf8_character_code}"}`
which could hint to a problem on the NPM side??

Ralf

Comment: But take into account that this install the latest version of node, and it may break compatibilities. For example when running lesscss it may require node 0.4.12 while at the time of writing thios comment, the automatically downloaded version is 0.7.9. See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717623/getting-an-error-when-running-the-less-css-compiler-in-node-js

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
git clone http://github.com/isaacs/npm.git
cd npm
sudo make install
```

Comment: great - this gives me aworking NPM. But I am still lost, as there is no working repository under the URL http://registry.npmjs.org/npm

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is an issue with the NPM registry at the moment - I was getting the same error, installed using git, and then discovered that the registry is down too.

See https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues for more about the registry being down - there could be an issue with the whole of NPM.